# Is the sloppy windows focus not working as it should?

Tags: gnome, window-management, focus, gnome-tweak-tool

I am using ubuntu 11.10, with gnome3.

I installed gnome-tweak-tool, in the `windows` menu, I selected `windowos focus mode`: `Sloppy`.

I had never heard of it before but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28computing%29#Sloppy_focus) sloppy focus means:

> The sloppyfocus model is a variant of the followfocus model. It allows input to continue to be collected by the last focused window when the mouse pointer is moved away from any window, such as over a menubar or desktop area.

I activated it, and I can't see no clear difference with the `mouse` focus mode, even when I'm typing on a text-box, it seems to completly grab focus of the other window?

My questions are:

- Did I understand what the sloppy mode should do? Should I be able to continue writing even when the mouse is on another window?
- Why is it not working and how do I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You have misinterpreted Sloppy Window focus mode. It is like Mouse mode (Focus Follows Mouse cursor) so you do not require mouse-clicks to change the active window.

If you want your current window to retain input focus even if you move the mouse cursor ANYWHERE else including over top other windows, then you want to set it to "Click" Windows focus mode. This means you will have to click on each window to make it active (when using the mouse to switch active windows). Note that this would be the same behaviour as Microsoft Windows.